# Similar to ``tabnanny``, how can I check that all the python code is using 4 spaces as an indent?

Tags: python, tabs

Similar to [tabnanny](http://docs.python.org/library/tabnanny.html), is there a utility for python to check if a python file is using 4 spaces for indentation?

Comment: What's wrong with "grep" to look for tabs?

Comment: tabnanny catches tabs just fine, but I want to catch people using 4 spaces for this block and 2 spaces indent for an inner block.

Comment: @Casey.  I'm using jedit and I'm having zero problems always doing an indent with 4 spaces.  The files I want to auto-check during regressions are being modified by a number of people and I want our team to all use the same number of spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 4):

[Pylint](http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) can check this among many other things. Here's a warning it gave me with a test file:

```
W:  3: Bad indentation. Found 3 spaces, expected 4
```

It's also possible to make it expect another indent type using this command line option:

```
--indent-string=<string>
             String used as indentation unit. This is usually "    " 
             (4 spaces) or "\t" (1 tab). [current: '    ']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try the reindent.py script, found in tools/scripts of your python install.

> Change Python (.py) files to use 4-space indents and no hard tab characters. Also trim excess spaces and tabs from ends of lines, and remove empty lines at the end of files. Also ensure the last line ends with a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Pylint (http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint) checks this (and much more).

Other Python code checkers (pep8, pyflakes, pychecker...) may do so too.